# How to run a Laravel serve that can be possible run also on LAN not only in my pc?

Tags: php, laravel, server, port, serve

I tried using this command but did not work.

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.2.20 --port 8000
```

**error:**

```
Laravel development server started: http://192.168.2.20:8000
[Sun Jan 24 20:54:26 2021] Failed to listen on 192.168.2.20:8000 (reason: The requested address is not valid in its context.
)
```

Comment: Just run in on localhost (127.0.0.1), then from the other machine specify the address (192.168.2.20)

Comment: @HTMHell will it work by using the ip ipconfig to the other device?

Comment: What do you mean using ip config to the other device? In your PC where you run the server, you need to find out your local IP address, you an do that by running ifconfig. Then, with any other device connected to the same network you should type in the browser `http://SERER_LOCAL_IP:8000` and it should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

Run this command:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

get your IPv4 address from ipconfig

for example: 192.168.1.10

And address ***192.168.1.10:8000*** is valid using in LAN

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell laravel to serve from your local IP. Just serve your app on localhost and then open your port for incoming requests based on your os and firewall. After that anyone can visit your laravel app on desired port just by typing 192.168.2.20:8000

Comment: How to enable the port for incoming requests?

Comment: what is your os?

Comment: I have Windows 10

Comment: first check if this works: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000. if that didn't work use this link to open port https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Comment: This will not work on WSL @Illyrian's answer works